# Magento 2.3.2 issue after update

Tags: upgrade, magento2.3.1

I upgrade my version of magento 2.1.6 to 2.3.2.
Now I have kind of problem with php bin/magento system:upgrade.
In **file system cleanup** the last line is :

> The directory '/var/www/MyWebSite/magento/generated/metadata/' doesn't
>   exist - skipping cleanup

In **Updating modules** / **schema post-updates** :

> Notice: Undefined index: getUpdateOnlineCart in
>   /var/www/MyWebSite/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/MethodsMap.php
>   on line 81

I don't fully understand what is the problem; someone have an idea ?

PS: if you need more info or in case of minus please let me know like that I can update my post

**EDIT**
Actually I am using this extension https://www.magestore.com/catalog/product/view/_ignore_category/1/id/208/s/magento-pos-integration-extension#overview-box, it is not compatible with magento 2.3 ? because the problem look to come from here

Comment: which is your php version

Comment: my php version is 7.1.32

Comment: please comment the app/etc/env.php file and run the setup step and check that all the php exension is install in your server, if yes than uncomment than file

Comment: you mean commenting app/etc/env.php and running php bin/magento setup:update ?

Comment: no just comment than file and open the url

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your codebase for "getUpdateOnlineCart". It's probably something in one of your theme files. Try disabling the module that contains it then retry php bin/magento set:up

for more detail:
 https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Version-Upgrades/Notice-Undefined-index-getUpdateOnlineCart-while-upgrading-to-2/td-p/127601

Comment: I disable the module, I can run setup:upgrade but setup:di:compile return the error MiBPHP Fatal error:  Cannot inherit previously-inherited or override constant MEDIA_GALLERY from interface Magestore\Webpos\Api\Data\Catalog\ProductInterface in /var/www/MyWebSite/magento/app/code/Magestore/Webpos/Model/Catalog/Product.php on line 32

Comment: did you disable the Magestore Webpos the module?

Comment: I did, disableling is not working, is needed to totally remove it from the source code and the database following this https://nwdthemes.com/2016/07/12/magento-2-uninstall-module/

Comment: @SylwekFr  are you got solution i am also same problem

Comment: @matinict yes I had to install the updated getUpdateOnlineCart, you have to check all of your module if they are up to date or no (because some of them even if they are "all life free update" require payment to update ...), if they are developed internally you have to check dependency for see where the update cause trouble

Answer (score 0):

Have you Upgraded Php Version which is required for Magento 2.3.2?

It might be due to incomplete Php Extensions which are not installed on your server or you can check in php.ini for any disabled PHP extension. make sure to enable it.

Comment: All extention are activated and I have php 7.1.32

Comment: I had this kind of errors while upgraded Magento from 2.1.5 to 2.3.2. I had it solved by enabling all PHP extensions though.

Comment: @MuzammalHassan can you name particular php extension need to use i am using php7.2